# how to send a curl request in PHP when using docker-compose without use IP of server

Tags: php, docker, curl

there is two `docker` container that created by `docker compose`. one of them send a `curl` request, and the other one sends back the respond. docker has a internal `DNS` server and i want to use host name instead of host `IP`.

once I used host name for deploy connection to `MySQL` but it didn't work for curl. docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  Panel:
    image: 'php:7.3.1-apache'
    volumes:
      - /home/user/php/Panel:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - '80:80'

  Authentication:
    image: 'php:7.3.1-apache'
    volumes:
      - /home/user/php/Authentication:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
```

the curl works with host IP and the request is :

```
$url = "http://192.168.60.128:8080";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
    ));
```

my curl request for host name is like this:

```
$curl = curl_init('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: Authentication'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

and there is no respond.

Comment: Use the port that the server inside the container is listening on; your `docker-compose.yml` suggests port 80.  If there's a `ports:` line, use the _second_ port number.  Connect to the name of the other container in the same way you'd make any other HTTP call using a DNS name (maybe `$url = "http://Authentication"`).